# HTTP_INTERCEPTOR not called in production mode (heroku)

Tags: angular, heroku, angular-http-interceptors

I have a problem with an app deployed on heroku configured with HTTP_INTERCEPTORS. The app backend is in Spring Framework and deployed in another heroku repository, while the frontend is Angular.

The interceptor is used to intercept request and refresh jwtTokens in the header.

I have written a simple console.log("httpRequest intercepted", req)to check if the intercept method is triggered.

What is strange to me is it is correctly called when launched in local but not when on heroku. Therefore the jwtToken is never refreshed and expires.

The other functions (login, signup, connection to DB etc.) work correctly.

Can you see something I do not ?

token-interceptor.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpInterceptor, HttpRequest, HttpHandler, HttpEvent, HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, BehaviorSubject, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { AuthService } from './auth/shared/auth.service';
import { catchError, switchMap, take, filter } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { LoginResponse } from './auth/login/login-response.payload';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class TokenInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

  isTokenRefreshing = false;
  refreshTokenSubject: BehaviorSubject<any> = new BehaviorSubject(null);

  constructor(public authService: AuthService) { }

  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    console.log("httpRequest intercepted", req)
    if (req.url.indexOf('refresh') !== -1 || req.url.indexOf('login') !== -1) {
      return next.handle(req);
    }
    const jwtToken = this.authService.getJwtToken();

    if (jwtToken) {
      return next.handle(this.addToken(req, jwtToken)).pipe(catchError(error => {
        if (error instanceof HttpErrorResponse
          && error.status === 403) {
          return this.handleAuthErrors(req, next);
        } else {
          return throwError(error);
        }
      }));
    }
    return next.handle(req);

  }

  private handleAuthErrors(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    if (!this.isTokenRefreshing) {
      this.isTokenRefreshing = true;
      this.refreshTokenSubject.next(null);

      return this.authService.refreshToken().pipe(
        switchMap((refreshTokenResponse: LoginResponse) => {
          this.isTokenRefreshing = false;
          this.refreshTokenSubject
            .next(refreshTokenResponse.authenticationToken);
          return next.handle(this.addToken(req,
            refreshTokenResponse.authenticationToken));
        })
      )
    } else {
      return this.refreshTokenSubject.pipe(
        filter(result => result !== null),
        take(1),
        switchMap((res) => {
          return next.handle(this.addToken(req,
            this.authService.getJwtToken()))
        })
      );
    }
  }

  addToken(req: HttpRequest<any>, jwtToken: any) {
    return req.clone({
      headers: req.headers.set('Authorization',
        'Bearer ' + jwtToken)
    });
  }

}
```

Header.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {AuthService} from '../auth/shared/auth.service';
import {Router} from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-header',
  templateUrl: './header.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./header.component.css']
})
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {

  isLoggedIn: boolean;
  username: string;

  constructor(private authService : AuthService, private router : Router){ }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.authService.loggedIn.subscribe((data: boolean) => this.isLoggedIn = data);
    this.authService.username.subscribe((data: string) => this.username = data);
    this.isLoggedIn = this.authService.isLoggedIn();
    this.username = this.authService.getUserName();
    console.log('header', this.isLoggedIn);
  }

  logout() {
    this.authService.logout();
    this.isLoggedIn = false;
    this.router.navigateByUrl('');
  }
}
```

auth.service.ts

```
import {EventEmitter, Injectable, Output} from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { SignupRequestPayload } from '../sign-up/signup-request.payload';
import {Observable, throwError} from 'rxjs';
import { LocalStorageService } from 'ngx-webstorage';
import { LoginRequestPayload } from '../login/login-request.payload';
import { LoginResponse } from '../login/login-response.payload';
import { map, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import {environment} from '../../../environments/environment';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService {

  @Output() loggedIn: EventEmitter<boolean> = new EventEmitter();
  @Output() username: EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter();

  refreshTokenPayload = {
    refreshToken: this.getRefreshToken(),
    username: this.getUserName()
  }

  baseUrl = environment.baseUrl;

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient,
              private localStorage: LocalStorageService) {
  }

  signup(signupRequestPayload: SignupRequestPayload): Observable<any> {
    return this.httpClient.post(this.baseUrl + 'api/auth/signup', signupRequestPayload, { responseType: 'text' });
  }

  login(loginRequestPayload: LoginRequestPayload): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.httpClient.post<LoginResponse>(this.baseUrl + 'api/auth/login',
      loginRequestPayload).pipe(map(data => {
      this.localStorage.store('authenticationToken', data.authenticationToken);
      this.localStorage.store('username', data.username);
      this.localStorage.store('refreshToken', data.refreshToken);
      this.localStorage.store('expiresAt', data.expiresAt);

      this.loggedIn.emit(true);
      this.username.emit(data.username);
      return true;
    }));
  }

  refreshToken() {
    return this.httpClient.post<LoginResponse>(this.baseUrl + 'api/auth/refresh/token',
      this.refreshTokenPayload)
      .pipe(tap(response => {
        this.localStorage.clear('authenticationToken');
        this.localStorage.clear('expiresAt');
        this.localStorage.store('authenticationToken', response.authenticationToken);
        this.localStorage.store('expiresAt', response.expiresAt);
      }));
  }

  logout() {
    this.httpClient.post(this.baseUrl + 'api/auth/logout', this.refreshTokenPayload,
      { responseType: 'text' })
      .subscribe(data => {
        console.log(data);
      }, error => {
        throwError(error);
      })
    this.localStorage.clear('authenticationToken');
    this.localStorage.clear('username');
    this.localStorage.clear('refreshToken');
    this.localStorage.clear('expiresAt');
  }

  getJwtToken() {
    console.log('triggered)')
    return this.localStorage.retrieve('authenticationToken');
  }

  getRefreshToken() {
    return this.localStorage.retrieve('refreshToken');
  }

  getUserName() {
    return this.localStorage.retrieve('username');
  }

  isLoggedIn(): boolean {
    return this.getJwtToken() != null;
  }
}
```

app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HeaderComponent } from './header/header.component';
import {HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, HttpClientModule} from '@angular/common/http';
import { MapComponent } from './map/map.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import {LoginComponent} from "./auth/login/login.component";
import {ReactiveFormsModule} from "@angular/forms";
import {BrowserAnimationsModule} from "@angular/platform-browser/animations";
import { ToastrModule } from 'ngx-toastr';
import {NgxWebstorageModule} from "ngx-webstorage";
import { CreateVehicleComponent } from './create-vehicle/create-vehicle.component';
import {TokenInterceptor} from './token-interceptor';
import { SignupComponent } from './auth/sign-up/sign-up.component';
import {NgbModule} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HeaderComponent,
    SignupComponent,
    MapComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    CreateVehicleComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    NgxWebstorageModule.forRoot(),
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    ToastrModule.forRoot(),
    NgbModule
  ],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: TokenInterceptor,
      multi: true
    }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Angular version

```
Angular CLI: 11.2.0
Node: 14.15.0
OS: win32 x64

Angular:
...
Ivy Workspace:

Package                      Version
------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect    0.1102.0 (cli-only)
@angular-devkit/core         11.2.0 (cli-only)
@angular-devkit/schematics   11.2.0 (cli-only)
@schematics/angular          11.2.0 (cli-only)
@schematics/update           0.1102.0 (cli-only)
```

My app is based on the work of Sai Upadhyayula in this tutorial : https://programmingtechie.com/2020/05/14/building-a-reddit-clone-with-spring-boot-and-angular/

Let me know if you need more details

Answer (score 0):

Did you tested your build in **production**  mode in local machine ? there could a environment file issues.

Try running Heroku locally , it will help in easy debugging / finding root cause

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-local